# how to make child element cover border of parent?

Tags: html, css

Here is a sort of rough picture of what I am trying to do. If it doesn't explain it well enough I can throw together a fiddle.

[image]

The black box is a `<div>` and the pink ones are also divs. What I want is for them to look *sort of* like tabs. So when one is active, it covers up the border of the parent giving the 'bridge' effect that is important in tabs.

I thought that I could just make the active one slightly more wide so it would cover up the border. The problem is if I have `overflow-x: hidden;` the wider part is 'beneath' the black outline and if I do auto or visible then it just lets it scroll.

One important thing: the pink need to have position relative.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: forgot to mention the most important part. The black box has `overflow-y: hidden`. Without it the methods below work fine, but when I add it, it goes back to how it was

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this approach will help you:

```css
.main {text-align: right;border: 10px solid #000;}
.main > div > div {width: 100px; height: 60px; display: inline-block;background-color: red;margin: 10px 0;}
.main > .selected > div {margin-right: -10px;padding-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="selected"><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cawu5/2/ I fixed that border issue, but I'm not sure if this works for your specific use case.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set a width on your container div, and not use `overflow-x hidden;`.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YhAmh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since your pink divs already have `position: relative`, you just offset the active ones a bit to the right:

```
.activediv{
    left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` you can achieve that layout with `overflow-y: hidden` in the parent `div`.

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/sqjck/